# Proving the existence of supremum for a sequence of measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to solve the following question , which goes as follows

Let $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$ be a sequence of measurable sets contained in a ball $B(0,1) \in R^n$. Assume that for some $\epsilon >0$ it is true that $ \lambda(A_k) \geq \epsilon$ for all k. Prove that there is some point which belongs to infinitely many A's.

My attempts - 
So fat I have tried to do two things , 
First I tried to prove that for any sequence of measurable sets which exists in  bounded in a measurable set itself must have a supremum . But then my friend proved the following fact
Suppose that E is a measurable subset of R. Suppose {Ei} is sequence of measurable subsets of E.For any x∈E,there exist an Nx such that for all n>Nx, we have x∉En. Since this proof worked for every x ,in E I thought that I would not be proof that the supremum existed .

It will be helpful if you could show me the correct way to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

$\cap_{m = 1}^{\infty} \cup_{k= m}^{\infty} A_k = A$ is the collection of points that appear in infinitely many of the sets $A_k$.

Using this formulation, can you bound $\lambda (A)$ from below? (If it has positive measure, then it must be non-empty.)

BTW - this is related (spiritually) to the Borel-Cantelli lemma(s).

Comment: I understand that the set you defined in the first line is the supremum . But I don't quite get how you are asking me to put a lower bound on $\lambda(A)$. I mean the way I see it is that its lowest measure may be $\epsilon$. I also see that it must a non empty set 
But I don't see how that will help me prove that the above sequence has a supremum which is in that set

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava Yes, $\lambda(A) \geq \epsilon$. (Do you see how to prove this?) So A is non-empty, and so there is a point in infinitely many $A_k$s. I don't understand what your follow up question is...

Comment: I don't understand how can you consider $supA_k$ to be all of A , since you are saying that ∩∞m=1∪∞k=mAk=A. And I thought that to solve this question we don't need to prove that λ(A)≥ϵ ! 
But could you please show me how to go about this proof ?

Comment: I understand that the lower bound on A can be applied by the countable additivity of the lebesgue measure . But I do not understand how that will lead to proving that there is a point which is there in all of the $A_i$ ?

Comment: Your question doesn't ask for a point in all of the A_i but only in infinitely many of them.